# BAT файл для автоматического подключения к серверу по SSH

Tags: ssh, bat

Клиент - Windows 7

Сервер - Ubuntu

На сервере работает `ssh` сервер. Подключаюсь по ключу без пароля.

Код в `bat` файле

```
start "" C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Git"\"git-bash.exe" login@server
```

После запуска `bat` файла на секунду открывается окно `git-bash` и сразу закрывается. Что это может быть?

Comment: Для начала залогируйте вывод в файл
start "" C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Git"\"git-bash.exe" login@server >>log

Comment: На рабочем столе создался файл log. Но он пустой

Comment: Я слабо представляю себе, что такое `git-bash.exe` но не нужно ли добавить там команду `ssh` перед `login@server`? И согласованность кавычек в строке мне как-то не очень.

Comment: start "" C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Git"\"git-bash.exe" login@server >>log 2>&1
 (2>&1 Означает перенаправлять ошибки в Log)

Comment: Ничего не изменилось. После запуска на несколько миллисекунд запускается командная строка и исчезает. На рабочем столе появляется пустой файл log.  Если запускать BAT файл с содержимым   start "" C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Git"\"git-bash.exe" то запускается нужное приложение, но мне нужно передать туда ssh данные

Comment: Что получается при таком варианте? `start "" C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Git"\"git-bash.exe" --login -i -c  login@server`